# Oracle regexp_replace with group

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I try this

`SELECT regexp_replace(v_gen,'(\b[a-zA-Z]+\b)','$$1%')INTO v_test FROM DUAL;`

It supose to transform `'hello world word'` in '`$hello% $world% $word%'`

The Oracle documentation is not clear about the founction `regexp_replace` with group...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
regexp_replace('hello world word','([a-zA-Z]+)','$\1%')
```

`\1` gives you the string matching the pattern and then we format it appending the other characters required.

`[a-zA-Z]+` looks for all continuous sequence of Alphabets.

`([[:alnum:]]+)` will look for sequence of alphanumeric characters. If you want one, you can use this.

**Example: With Multiple options**

```
with my_text as
(
  select 'hello world word' as str from dual
)
SELECT regexp_replace(str,'([[:alnum:]]+)','$\1%') FROM my_text
union all
SELECT regexp_replace(str,'([[:alpha:]]+)','$\1%') FROM my_text
union all
SELECT regexp_replace(str,'([a-zA-Z]+)','$\1%') FROM my_text

REGEXP_REPLACE(STR,'([
----------------------
$hello% $world% $word%
$hello% $world% $word%
$hello% $world% $word%
```

[SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/32562)

Comment: I agree with your approach, but you should change '%\1$' to '$\1%' to correspond with the requirement.